# What is this kind of door weatherstripping called?

Tags: weatherstripping

It is an entry door. This weather stripping is made of metal. The portion on the door interlocks with the portion on the jamb.

Door:
[image: door]

Jamb:
[image: jamb]

It is broken at the bottom corner of the door and I am trying to identify it to find replacement.
[image: broken]

Comment: Take a picture of the actual weather striping, by opening the door.

Comment: @Ruskes, the door is open in the pictures. The pictures depict the weather stripping. There is nothing else there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have there is "interlocking metal casement", and for weatherproofing it is available as "interlocking metal weather stripping"